# Installing Sagemath 10.3 on ubuntu

Tags: sagemath

I want to install Sagemath version 10.3 on ubuntu, I have downloaded the file sage-10.3.beta1.tar.gz, I want just some steps or pictures to install it.

Comment: Here you are: Just some steps...[How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 0):

Read [Installing from source](https://Look%20at%20%5B1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/source.html#sec-installation-from-sources) and, after unpacking the sage-10.3.beta1.tar.gz archive, the README.md.